# Cannot see any files in the directory

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I'm on Arch Linux and I've followed [this guide from Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Very_Secure_FTP_Daemon#Limiting_user_loginhttps://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Very_Secure_FTP_Daemon#Limiting_user_login)
I'm new to all of these but I've `ip address show` to access it from my mac to that address by `ftp://xx.xx.xx.xx`. I've created a simple `test.txt` file to see if the connection is actually working. I've connected it from my mac with **Go > Connect to Server** and it actually connected. But the folder  it has opened is still empty. I chose Guest when logging in because anonymous users are fine for me since it's a home network.

Here's my /etc/vsftpd.conf

```
pam_service_name=vsftpd
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_root=/home/zett/Work/WFP
anon_root=/home/zett/Work/WFP
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
anon_other_write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
ftpd_banner=Welcome on bla ftp
local_umask=022
anon_world_readable_only=NO
max_clients=10te
local_max_rate=10000000
max_per_ip=100
```

Comment: "I've created a simple test.txt file": where is this file?

Comment: It's in /home/zett/Work/WFP, as well as /srv/ftp/ just to make it sure. but nothing is showing up. @terdon